# Что такое "полноводная равнина"? После "и всё же" возможно тире?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, точное-словоупотребление

> И всё же – с VII века аграрные территории вдоль горной реки Рашки,
>   прихотливый бег которой выводил к полноводной равнине, номинально
>   находились под Византийским владычеством, так получили свою веру.

И получилось:

***аграрные территории с полноводной равниной получили свою веру...***

Ой-ё.

А с "Византийским владычеством" что?

Comment: А в чём _прихотливость бега_ реки? Чтобы выводить её не куда-нибудь, а к "полноводным (затопленным водой) равнинам"?

Comment: У, змий. Всё хиханьки да хаханьки. А нет бы помочь немолодой деушке.

Comment: Я привёл робкую, но правдоподобную гипотезу о сущности полноводной равнины... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*И всё же – с VII века аграрные территории вдоль горной реки Рашки, прихотливый бег которой выводил **к полноводным равнинным рекам**, номинально находились под Византийским владычеством, получив таким образом свою веру.*

1) Тире авторское, а автор волен сделать паузу там, где считает нужным.

2) Полноводной равнины, скорее всего, быть не может, надо чем-то заменить.

3) Под византийским владычеством. Пример: Болгария под византийским владычеством.

https://studfiles.net/preview/7158464/page:2/

Comment: Ога. Нетути полноводных равнин. А то я подумала, что крыша едет. А означенное владычество со строчной.